# Linux - Split CSV according to condition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, split, conditional-statements

I have a large CSV file with the following records:

```
60,1572236,3,58394247,\N,\N,\N,1925720,\N,2011-11-25 12:55:53,2011-11-25 12:55:53
61,2875109,4,58394209,1234,\N,4025175,\N,\N,2011-11-25 12:55:53,2011-11-25 12:55:53
62,2875109,4,58394209,\N,\N,\N,9860904,\N,2011-11-25 12:55:53,2011-11-25 12:55:53
63,2875109,5,58394209,8756,\N,\N,8615157,\N,2011-11-25 12:55:53,2011-11-25 12:55:53
64,2686696,3,58394211,\N,\N,59512,\N,\N,2011-11-25 12:55:53,2011-11-25 12:55:53
65,2686696,3,58394211,\N,\N,4025893,\N,\N,2011-11-25 12:55:53,2011-11-25 12:55:53
```

I want to split the file into 2 file, the condition for the split will be the value in the 5th column, one file will get the rows with no value in that column (\N) and columns with value in that column will go to another file.

in the example above: rows 2,4 will go to one file and the rest of the rows will go to another file.

any ideas how to do this in linux?

Comment: I know that this does not answer your question about using Linux commands. But, if you have some time to study it, I suggest you to take a look at R. You can have your CSV file imported as a Data Frame. Then, according to whatever rule you define (they are like conditional expressions in programming languages), you can have other data frames generated from the original one. Then, you can export them as CSV files.

Comment: You could use `grep` to match the first condition via a regular expression then `cut -d, -f2,4` to extract the second and fourth columns to a new file.

Comment: my file has over 70M rows i just added a view lines so you could see how the data looks like, i dont know which rows have/dont have the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, '$5=="\\N"{print >"file1.csv"; next}; {print >"file2.csv"}' data.csv
```

- `file1.csv` will contains `\N`
- `file2.csv` will contains others